# How to add a photo to the marketplace on Facebook? C# selenium

Tags: c#, image, visual-studio, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I writes a program for adding ads to a marketplace. In C #. I wonder how I can add a photo to this ad. Maybe some path? I say right away that I don't want to use the API yet. I can choose this photo manually, but I want everything done automatically. I will be grateful for any help.

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using System.Threading;

namespace MARKETPLACE_v2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        string url = "https://www.facebook.com/";

        ChromeDriver driver; Thread th;

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.AddArguments("--disable-notifications"); // to disable notification
            driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[normalize-space()='Akceptuj wszystkie']")).Click();

            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@id='email']")).SendKeys("login");

            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@id='pass']")).SendKeys("password");

            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[contains(text(),'Zaloguj się')]")).Click();

            //login

            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[name()='path' and contains(@d,'M17.5 23.7')]")).Click(); Thread.Sleep(2000);

            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='j83agx80 cbu4d94t d6urw2fd dp1hu0rb l9j0dhe7 du4w35lb']//span[@class='d2edcug0 hpfvmrgz qv66sw1b c1et5uql lr9zc1uh a8c37x1j keod5gw0 nxhoafnm aigsh9s9 d3f4x2em fe6kdd0r mau55g9w c8b282yb iv3no6db jq4qci2q a3bd9o3v lrazzd5p knomaqxo']//span[1]")).Click(); Thread.Sleep(3000);

            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[contains(text(),'Przedmiot na sprzedaż')]")).Click(); Thread.Sleep(3000);

            IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@type='file']"));

            element.SendKeys(@"C:\download\maciek.jpg");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you inspect the Upload photo button in the browser and copy/paste the HTML into your question

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are trying :

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='s45kfl79 emlxlaya bkmhp75w spb7xbtv bp9cbjyn rt8b4zig n8ej3o3l agehan2d sk4xxmp2 rq0escxv pq6dq46d taijpn5t l9j0dhe7 tdjehn4e qypqp5cg q676j6op']//i[@class='hu5pjgll lzf7d6o1']")).Click(); // now i can choose a photo from my computer
```

line of code to open a prompt, where you can navigate to the file and select the file and finally can upload, right ?

But we don't have to do this after `Selenium 3`.

Instead, if in that page you see any `input` tag that has `attribute` equals to type and `value` is `file`, I repeat any `input` `tag` that has those `property` you can directly do `SendKeys()`.

Also when I inspected Facebook marketplace page, I could see : -

```
<input accept="image/*,image/heif,image/heic,video/*,video/mp4,video/x-m4v,video/x-matroska,.mkv" class="mkhogb32" multiple="" type="file">
```

so remove the line

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='s45kfl79 emlxlaya bkmhp75w spb7xbtv bp9cbjyn rt8b4zig n8ej3o3l agehan2d sk4xxmp2 rq0escxv pq6dq46d taijpn5t l9j0dhe7 tdjehn4e qypqp5cg q676j6op']//i[@class='hu5pjgll lzf7d6o1']")).Click();
```

and put this :

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@type='file']")).SendKeys("full file path which you want to upload")
```

should directly upload the files without opening the prompt.

Comment: I tried this way and it doesn't work. Maybe I'm doing something wrong?
     driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@type='file']")).SendKeys(@"C:\Photo.jpg");

Comment: `driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@type='file']")).SendKeys("C:\Capture.jpg"); ` do this, remove that @, also try to place file in your project folder.

Comment: still not working, when delete @ shows me an error  "unrecognized escape sequence "

Comment: @thomas2075 : Can you share the exact code the you have used ?

Comment: I edited the code in the post. I tried to do it recently using the IWebElement method and a variable (I also tried to send a picture to a google graphic this way and it worked.

Comment: but when i try the same method with facebook i get an error: OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: 'element not interactable